# How to style a date-picker input like a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, css, datepicker

I've made a little calendar app, in which one can add events with a starting date and settings for repetion. So it can occur daily or weekly or monthly. In this Snippet you can see the Text if you chose daily repetition.

Now i wonder if it is possible to style the Datefield like a normal paragraph which still has a dropdown-datepicker. How could i do that?

```js
function rrendClose() {
    document.getElementById('dailyText').innerText = "Takes place every day.";
    document.getElementById('dailyEnddate').style.visibility = "collapse";
    document.getElementById('dailyDismiss').style.visibility = "collapse";
    document.getElementById('showFullDaily').style.visibility = "visible";
  }

  function rrendOpen() {
    document.getElementById('dailyText').innerText = "Takes place every day, until";
    document.getElementById('dailyEnddate').style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById('dailyDismiss').style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById('showFullDaily').style.visibility = "collapse";
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <p class="pt-1"><p class="ml-3" id="dailyText">Takes place evry day, until</p>
    <a id="showFullDaily" class="link" onclick="rrendOpen();" style="visibility: collapse;" >Add enddate</a>
    <input name="rrend" class="col-5 form-control border border-dark auto-date" type="date" id="dailyEnddate" value="{{date("d.m.Y")}}">
    <button type="button" id="dailyDismiss" class="close col-1" aria-label="Close" onclick="rrendClose();">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just take the input and use css to remove the outline and padding, right?

Comment: yeah i think so.. I have some other problems with CSS because it inherits from some other elements, but i think i am able to find all of that and set the right styles.. thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some changes:

- Remove the textbox-related styles (specifically the border and padding) and then making it "inherit" the font styles.
- `showFullDaily` was switched to use the `display` property instead of `visibility` because the latter, while hides the element visibly, leaves space where the text should be, while display does not.
- `dailyText` was changed from a `p` tag to a `span` because 1) `p` tags should not be nested within each other and 2) `span` is an inline element, so it naturally continues the flow without additional styles. All of these changes together allows the input element to collapse and flow with the paragraph.

```js
function rrendClose() {
    document.getElementById('dailyText').innerText = "Takes place every day.";
    document.getElementById('dailyEnddate').style.visibility = "collapse";
    document.getElementById('dailyDismiss').style.visibility = "collapse";
    document.getElementById('showFullDaily').style.display = "block";
  }

  function rrendOpen() {
    document.getElementById('dailyText').innerText = "Takes place every day, until";
    document.getElementById('dailyEnddate').style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById('dailyDismiss').style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById('showFullDaily').style.display = "none";
  }
```

```css
#dailyEnddate {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <p class="pt-1"><span class="ml-3" id="dailyText">Takes place evry day, until</span>
    <a id="showFullDaily" class="link" onclick="rrendOpen();" style="display: none;" >Add enddate</a>
    <input name="rrend" class="col-5 form-control border border-dark auto-date" type="date" id="dailyEnddate" value="{{date("d.m.Y")}}">
    <button type="button" id="dailyDismiss" class="close col-1" aria-label="Close" onclick="rrendClose();">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to CSS and type:

```
.row {

display: flex

}
```